# How to use TcpListener NetworkStream in F#?

Tags: c#, tcp, f#, porting, tcplistener

I'm trying to port the C# example code from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx, and I'm having trouble on the reading the data part. How should `Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];` be written in F#?

```
open System
open System.Net
open System.Net.Sockets

let ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
let port = 1000

let tcpListener = TcpListener(ipAddress, port)

let rec listen() =
    printfn "Listening..."
    let tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()
    printfn "Connected!"
    let networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
    // port Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256]; to F#
    listen()

try
    tcpListener.Start()
    listen()
with
    | error -> printfn "%s" error.Message

Console.Read() |> ignore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an empty array using the `Array.zeroCreate` function. Adding that to your code, the `listen` function would look something like this:

```
let rec listen() =
    let tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()
    let networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
    let buffer = Array.zeroCreate 256
    let read = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, 256)
    // Do something with 'buffer' and 'read'
    listen()
```

Comment: You probably want to kick everything after the `AcceptTcpClient` call to a forked thread though. Otherwise your server will have downtime while you're processing.